# Web form that you can enter APO/FPO and USA addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, street-address

I have a web form that is used to gather contact information for a GED verification service. We're starting to get a lot of requests to send the verification's to **APO/FPO** addresses. Tried Googling/Binging for some examples but there is nothing available on how to create an accessible and usable form that can handle the extra information. 
( examples: [USPS - APO/FPO/DPO Guidlines](https://www.usps.com/ship/apo-fpo-guidelines.htm) )

Currently we ask for name, address, address 2, state, city and zip. An APO/FPO address has no city or state, just a name, location and a zip with some extra text in front. I was thinking of offering two separate forms that would be selectable at the beginning of the collection process, one for a normal USA address format and another for the APO/FPO format.

Comment: Here at work, we use a hyperlink to change the form that the user sees when using an APO/FPO address.  Perhaps you could take that approach as well?

Comment: Have you thought about combining all the fields into one textarea? (See smartystreets.com homepage.) This would allow the user to enter their address any way they feel comfortable. Plus, a CASS-Certified service can validate it and split it into components for you. (Plug: I'm a street genie at SmartyStreets.)

Comment: "put on hold as off-topic"  Not sure why, but I was simply looking for some other examples on how to handle this type of Form. Couldn't' find anything else. Accepted Nicholas Carey answer as it explained how to incorporate it into a standard form. He also explained what the two letter designation and zip are used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail to US Military overseas addresses and diplomatic pouch (APO = Army Post Office, FPO = Fleet Post Office, DPO = Diplomatic Post Office) is a little weird:

- The address line(s) are dependent on the destination. Land-based units will need the mail center/box number. Navy (FPO) is different: mail destined to a sailor aboard ship should have the ship's name and number as the address, something like

  ```
  Seaman Sarah Cambell
  USS Enterprise (CVG-65)
  FPO AP 96543-1234
  ```
- The **city** field is one of

  - APO (Army Post Office)
  - FPO (Fleet Post Office)
  - DPO (Diplomatic Post Office)
- The **state** field is one of

  - AA (Armed Forces Americas, serving all of the Americas except Canada, including military bases within the United States).
  - AE (Armed Forces Europe, serving Europe, Canada, Africa and the Middle East).
  - AP (Armed Forces Pacific, serving Asia and the Pacific).
- The zip code is the military zip code, tied to the gateway designated by the *state* field.

More at https://stamps.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/774